# How to Create Search TextField like Nokia?

Tags: textfield, lwuit

In Nokia S40 the search field for the contacts is looked like this

[image]

This `TextField` is really interactive, if I put some text the magnifier will change into x `Button`. I've tried to create the `TextField` in LWUIT and override the paint methods to put the magnifier image but it can't use as a button.

Are there any component I can use to recreate something like this (Especially with LWUIT)? Or maybe are there any ready-to-be-used component from Nokia to create something like this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to that, but it won't look like the native SearchField, but it will work fine.

What you can do is this.
Create a container with a boxLayoutX and put inside it a `TextField` and a `Button`. When you capture that the `TextField` has text inside, change the Image attached to the `Button` to a X and here it is. You only need to implement the functionallity of the `Button`.

Comment: actually this is not the something what I looking for, but yeah, the only thing to do it is this way (I think so). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TextField has a `setHintIcon` method allowing you to do just that.